# Почему скрипт умирает при R::exec?

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Этот вопрос будет состоять из двух частей. 
Первая: 
Я произвожу вставку в таблицу через функцию  `R::exec`, 
в случае если вставка является не удачной ( по условию из БД ) весь PHP скрипт умирает( меня выкидывает с ошибкой 500). Как этого избежать?
Вторая: Как проверить успешность вставки в БД?( я нашел у RedBean функцию `"$id=R::getInsertID()"` и я собирался проверять существует ли ``id или нет, но так как всё умирает до `"R::getInsertID()"`, то я не знаю как это реализовать)

```
    require 'con.php';
$name = $_POST['client_name'];

if($name)
{
    R::exec("INSERT INTO `table` (`name`) VALUES (?)", array(
    $name
    ));
}
else{ echo json_encode("plz Help for this code!");}
$new_id = R::getInsertID();
$error = "ALL IS BAD";
if($new_id)
{
    echo json_encode($new_id);
}
else
{
    echo json_encode($error);
}

R::close();
```

Comment: Проверьте документацию вашей библиотеки для R о функции exec, там будут моменты о том, как обрабатывать ошибки (или исключения?), связанные с вашими запросами через неё.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov я нашел вот такое описание для функции `PDO::exec()` "В этом примере разработчик допустил ошибку, полагаясь на возвращаемый результат PDO::exec(). В результате, если запрос отработал без ошибок, но не модифицировал ни одной строки, работа скрипта будет завершена функцией die():", думаю оно подойдет и для  `R::exec`.